# Setter in property trigger fails if target property already has an explicit value

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I'm currently trying to create a `ControlTemplate` for the `Button` class in WPF, replacing the usual visual tree with something that makes the button look similar to the little (X) close icon on Google Chrome's tabs. I decided to use a `Path` object in XAML to achieve the effect. Using a property trigger, the control responds to a change in the IsMouseOver property by setting the icon's red background.

Here's the XAML from a test app:

```
<Window x:Class="Widgets.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">

  <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="borderStyle" TargetType="Border">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
              <SolidColorBrush Color="#CC0000"/>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="closeButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
      <Border Width="12" Height="12" CornerRadius="6"
              BorderBrush="#AAAAAA" Background="Transparent"
              Style="{StaticResource borderStyle}"
              ToolTip="Close">
        <Viewbox Margin="2.75">
          <Path Data="M 0,0 L 10,10 M 0,10 L 10,0" Stroke="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Border, AncestorLevel=1}}" StrokeThickness="1.8"/>
        </Viewbox>
      </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid Background="White">
    <Button Template="{StaticResource closeButtonTemplate}"/>
  </Grid>

</Window>
```

Note that the circular background is always there - it's just transparent when the mouse isn't over it.

The problem with this is that the trigger just isn't working. Nothing changes in the button's appearance. However, if I remove the `Background="Transparent"` value from the `Border` object in the `ControlTemplate`, the trigger *does* work (albeit only when over the 'X').

I really can't explain this. Setters for any other properties placed in the `borderStyle` resource work fine, but the `Background` setter fails as soon as the default background is specified in the `ControlTemplate`.

Any ideas why it's happening and how I can fix it? I know I could easily replace this code with, for example, a .PNG-based image, but I want to understand why the current implementation isn't working.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try moving the explict "Background" assignment from inside the Border declaration to the Style itself:

```
<Style x:Key="borderStyle" TargetType="Border">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />

    <Style.Triggers> 
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"> 
            <Setter Property="Background"> 
            <Setter.Value> 
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#CC0000"/> 
            </Setter.Value> 
        </Setter> 
    </Trigger> 
</Style.Triggers> 

...

<Border Width="12" Height="12" CornerRadius="6" 
        BorderBrush="#AAAAAA" 
        Style="{StaticResource borderStyle}" 
        ToolTip="Close">
```

Styles can't override a property that has been explicitly set. You need to set the value in the style.

Comment: Wow, that works - thanks! Wonder how I never came across this before. Do you have a reference (e.g. MSDN article) that describes this limitation of styles?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but it comes up here quite often. :)

Comment: Found a reference on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#multiple_sets

Comment: Thank you very much for this, Matt! You just saved my head from my desk.

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is that the Border does not 'catch' the mouse events when it is transparant.

To verify - try changing the background to #01FFFFFF instead of Transparent.

Comment: Nope, that's not it. I specifically used Transparent because it *does* catch mouse events (unlike a null brush).